# I need to leave the biggest object in image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, object-detection

I need to detect the biggest object from image with ImageMagick. It can be bigger or smaller, or can be in other location. It's always black, and background always white.
[image]

Comment: You should say where you need this (java, C, C#, C++, android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this with Connected Component Analysis

```
convert objects.png -define connected-components:verbose=true      \
   -define connected-components:area-threshold=100                 \
   -connected-components 8 -auto-level output.png

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 595x842+0+0 296.7,420.0 499414 gray(255)
  7: 37x30+342+632 360.0,646.5 1110 gray(0)
  3: 12x15+465+375 470.5,382.0 180 gray(0)
  1: 23x12+439+332 447.9,335.4 150 gray(0)
  6: 13x16+451+425 456.6,430.6 136 gray(0)
```

The first object listed (the first line) is a white object, because the `mean-color` is gray(255), and is therefore the background, so I ignore that. The second one is the largest (area=1110) and I can draw a red rectangle around it like this

```
convert objects.png -stroke red -strokewidth 5 -fill none -draw "rectangle 342,632 379,662" out.png
```

[image]

If you want to mask out all objects outside the bounding box of the largest object, you can do that like this:

```
convert objects.png -alpha on            \
   \( +clone                             \
      -evaluate set 0                    \
      -fill white                        \
      -draw "rectangle 342,632 379,662"  \
      -alpha off                         \
   \) -compose copy-opacity -composite result.png
```

Basically the part inside the parentheses copies the original image (`+clone`), fills it with black (`-evaluate set 0`), then draws a white box over the bounding box of the biggest shape, then uses that black and white mask to set the opacity of the original image that we started off with. That leaves you with this:

[image]